# Is there a way to change the boolean status of a django model by changing the boolean status of another model

Tags: django-models, boolean

This is my UserProfile model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from user_membership.models import UserMembership


class UserProfile(models.Model):
      user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
      last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
      phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
      city = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
      membership = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.first_name
```

This is my UserMembership model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class MembershipType(models.TextChoices):
    MONTH = 'Month'
    SEMESTER = 'Semester'

class Action(models.TextChoices):
    REQUESTED = 'Requested'
    ACCEPTED = 'Accepted'
    PENDING = 'Pending'
    Rejected = 'Rejected'

class UserMembership(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    student_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='')
    membership_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=MembershipType.choices, default=MembershipType.MONTH)
    payment_slip = models.ImageField(upload_to='payment_slips')
    membership_action = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Action.choices, default=Action.REQUESTED)
    membership_accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

My question is: Is it possible to or How can I change the boolean status of UserProfile.membership by changing the boolean status of the UserMembership.membership_accepted !! Thank you in advance

Comment: Just remove the field and work with annotations when you need this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to just *remove* the `membership` field and work with annotations when you the database to determine this, so:

```
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

User.objects.annotate(
    accepted=Coalesce('usermembership__membership_accepted', Value(False))
)
```

The `User`s that arise from this `QuerySet` will have an extra attribute `accepted` that will be `True` in case there is a related `UserMembership` record with `membership_accepted` set to `True`.

This is also more *robust*: if you later remove the `UserMembership` object of that user, or you set `membership_accepted` to `False`, then `membership` will be set to `False` in the annotated value as well. It is easy to forget a usercase where you want to (re)set the membership and thus not update the field accordingly.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).